# ArangoDb .Net driver doesn't handle enum

Tags: arangodb

I am a newbie for ArangoDB and I am trying to make some CRUD operation but I am stucked whenever getting to entity object with `Enum`.

It prompted me the message like this.

```
System.InvalidCastException : 
Invalid cast from 'System.Int64' to 'Testing.Sample.Repository.EventAction'.
```

`EventAction` is actually an `Enum` type. Once I switch it to integer and it works. I am wondering can I use enum for my case as it is more convenience to handle than using integer. Thanks.

Comment: Which driver version are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Enum type is not standard JSON type, driver serialize it as integer value. Deserialization might not be supported in the driver version you are using, however new version is going to be released soon with support for Enum type deserialization in strongly typed objects.

Comment: Hi. Yojimbo87. I am using the strong typed in fact. I am glad that the new released will support that. I can't wait to see that. To be frank. I just tried ArangoDB for few days but I few it is really a great NoSQL solution. It's just that the .Net driver let me feel that .Net developers are second class citizen. I am still evaluating and would not mind to pay for the basic subscription if the .Net driver is good. After all, we are paying for SQL server too. Your pricing model is much lucrative as compare to SQL

Comment: @user1003132 Hi, I'm developing the driver in my free time as an open source project and use it in several projects. You can already use the upcoming new version if you clone and build 'reimplement' branch from https://github.com/yojimbo87/ArangoDB-NET/tree/reimplement which also contains new docs for almost every available operation. Any feedback or suggestion is very welcome and it can be discussed in details on ArangoDB google groups https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/arangodb

Comment: Hi Yojimbo87. Thanks a lot. You are really fast. I shall try the new version out.

Comment: Hi Yojimbo87, Can I download from Nuget?

Comment: @user1003132 It's not yet on nuget, but if you clone the git repository then you can build 'reimplement' branch which will give you Arango.Client.dll that you can use.

Comment: Hi, Yojimbo87. Thanks a lot. I will try the new dll. It is indeed much better as I a lot of things have been resolved. Nice job. How I wish can vote up again

Comment: @user1003132 I'm glad that the new version will resolve a lot of things for you. Your feedback and suggestions are more important for me than the upvotes :)

Comment: @user1003132 a short introduction of myself. I'm one of the founders of the company behind ArangoDB. I would love to discuss your questions about official support for the .net driver via mail with you. It would be great if you can contact me. claudius@arangodb.com